# REST API Best practice for image links

Tags: vb.net, rest, web-services, wcf, api-design

I am working on a REST API and I was wondering what is a better approach when it comes to populating image URLs.

In my case, I want to populate the image in different dimensions depending on the location it appears in. For example, in some places I want the image to appear as 50 x 50 px. However, in other places I want it to appear as 500 x 500 px.

I created a function `DrawImage(ImageSRC, width)` that reconstructs the image using `System.Drawing` in .NET according to the width provided. This way I will use a 50 x 50 px image instead of 500 x 500 px image whenever I don't actually need to load the big image.

My question is, what is a better approach?

---

**Approach 1 (The traditional approach):** Providing a full image path in the REST API and handling the image reconstruction in the code:

**REST API**

```
[{
    "title": "Article title",
    "image": "http://somdomain.com/PathToImage/ImageName.png"
}]
```

**Code:**

```
ImageSrc = "http://somdomain.com/PathToImage/ImageName.png";
Width = 50;
<img alt="" src="DrawImage(ImageSRC, width)" />

// Or image population can be like this:
//<img alt="" src="http://somdomain.com/PageThatCallsTheFunctionDrawImage" />
```

---

**Approach 2:** Providing the value of the image in the REST API as a function and the parameters are passed by the API being called:

**REST API**

```
[{
    "title": "Article title",
    "image": "DrawImage('http://somdomain.com/PathToImage/ImageName.png', 50)"
}]
```

**Code:**

```
VALUE_OF_IMAGE_IN_API = DrawImage("http://somdomain.com/PathToImage/ImageName.png", 50);

<img alt="" src="VALUE_OF_IMAGE_IN_API" />
```

Comment: any reason for using REST API's to send back images? Why not let the client just grab the image and display it the way they need it to? Seems a little overkill to me...

Comment: @Ahmedilyas That was the argument with my coworker. I wanted to go with the first approach (simplest). However, my coworker suggested the second approach for an easier population in our case scenario.

My concern was that if the API got public, clients won't be able to handle the images without a proper documentation. I agree that approach 2 complicates things up but I just wanted to share and hear different feedbacks from all around.

Comment: yeah it's overkill. You now need to develop auth for your REST API so even if it goes public, they still need to auth.... unless your API is doing some heavy duty type image processing/creation, this is totally overkill.